# How can I print a message for each substitution in my Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl

I use the following Perl syntax in my bash script:

```
     perl -i –pe  'next if /^ *#/; s/(\b|\D)$ENV{OLD }(\b|\D)/$1$ENV{NEW }$2/'   file
```

I want to find the OLD word without first "#" character in the file ,  then replaces the OLD word with NEW word

My question: I want to print "replace $OLD with $NEW" each time perl replace the $OLD with $NEW

In which way? we can insert the command:  print "replaced $OLD with $NEW ";  in the Perl syntax?

Please notice that perl one-liner syntax is part of my bash script

Comment: Have you considered rewriting your bash script in Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perl -i –pe  'next if /^ *#/; s/(\b|\D)$ENV{OLD }(\b|\D)/$1$ENV{NEW }$2/ && warn "replaced $OLD with $NEW\n"' file`

Comment: The -i switch makes the output from `print` go to the current file. I guess this was not desired by the OP

Comment: You should check the result of the s/// to see if you actually made a substitution. ;)

Comment: @eugene Thank you. I knew that ;-) @brian *Sigh* I know, I know. Thank you for the edit. I guess I jumped the gun.

Answer (score 1):

> perl -i –pe 'next if /^ *#/;
>   s/(\b|\D)$ENV{OLD }(\b|\D)/$1$ENV{NEW
>   }$2/ && print STDERR "replaced $OLD with
>   $NEW\n"' file